# Номер последнего (самого большого) id в таблице MySQL

Tags: mysql, php, функции

Как найти в определённой таблице базы данных MYSQL и вывести номер последнего id (или самого большого id)?

Нужно занести в переменную номер последнего id из определённой таблицы. Пробовал  функцию max():

```
$id_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data", $db);
$id = mysql_fetch_array($id_q);
$uploads = max($id);
```

Выдаёт 0. И пробовал функцию `mysql_insert_id()`:

```
$uploads =  printf ("Последняя вставленая запись имеет id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

Выдаёт 71 (количество всех id в базе).

Как сделать, чтобы делал выборку из определённой таблицы, например data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select max(`id`) as `maxid` from `data`
```

- не?

Answer (score 3):

Так прямо в запросе впишите... Если не ошибаюсь (id это имя поля содержащего id):

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM data
```

UPD: сорри, меня опередили но видимо уровня чтоб удалить коммент не хватает

Answer (score 2):

а с помощью вот этого запроса идентификатор строки можно получить

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY FROM `data`
```

хотя это только после инсерта :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]